# How to Sum from query search result

Tags: asp-classic, sum

I want to SUM from a query search result. I  have a table called Students. I created a Search form to list students with scores from Jan or Feb, by date range. The results are different (two rows, four rows, so on) based on how many months I search. I created a Sum row at the bottom to count the total from that column for Jan or Feb. However, it doesn't work at all.
Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Student Name</td>
    <td>Jan</td>
    <td>Feb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%=oRs("Name")%></td>
    <td <%=sRowStyle%>><%=oRs("Jan")%></td>
    <td <%=sRowStyle%>><%=oRs("Feb")%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><% total = total + CInt(oRs("Jan")) oRs.MoveNext WEND %>
  </td>
  <tr>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Could you write all code, within the query?

Comment: Agreed, I think it should be handled wherever you are grabbing the data.

Comment: When you say it's not working, what happens? Also, what is up with that `total = total +...` line? Is it missing some colons or line breaks? Do you want it looping in the middle of a TD? Maybe you should add some more of your code - the bit with the WHILE.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't defined where your recordset loop starts

Try this:

```
<% Dim CountJan, CountFeb
   Do while not oRS.eof %>
<tr>
    <td><%=oRs("Name")%></td>
    <td <%=sRowStyle%>><%=oRs("Jan")%></td>
    <td <%=sRowStyle%>><%=oRs("Feb")%></td>
  </tr>
<% CountJan = CountJan + Cint(oRs("Jan"))
   CountFeb = CountFeb + Cint(oRs("Feb"))
   oRs.MoveNext
   Loop
 %>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%=CountJan%></td>
    <td><%=CountFeb%></td>
  </tr>
```

You can use `while` and `wend` instead of `do while not` and `loop`, its a matter of personal preference

Comment: I like `do until` - `loop` myself. Why say "not (not condition)" when you can just say "condition"?

Comment: I have always done `Do while not oRS.eof` myself but @Martha makes a good point.

Comment: Kindly marks the answer that works as "the Answer"... it helps to clear these from peoples' queues as they attempt to help people who have no yet identified a working solution.

Comment: Hi @JennyTran if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.